# In recursive functions do we need to return the function explicitly in the body?

Tags: python, recursion, return, greatest-common-divisor

I was instructed to find gcd using the Euclid method. I initially wrote the following in Python:

```
def gcdRecur(a,b):
    if b==0:
        print('I am here')
        return a
    else:
        gcdRecur(b,a%b)
        print(a,b)

print(gcdRecur(51,187))
```

The result was:

```
I am here
34 17
51 34
187 51
51 187
None
```

I had no idea why its output is the way it is, then I realised looking at others code that one is to use the return statement explicitly.

```
def gcdRecur(a,b):
    if b==0:
        print('I am here')
        return a
    else:
        return gcdRecur(b,a%b)
        print(a,b)


print(gcdRecur(51,187))
```

I got

```
I am here
17
```

So I got what I wanted and learnt that we should use return statement rather then just calling the function.

My question is why is the output of the first code reversed? And why does the following code work even though no return statement is used

```
def tower(n,fr,to,spare):
    if n==1:
        print_move(fr,to)
    else:
        tower(n-1,fr,spare,to)
        tower(1,fr,to,spare)
        tower(n-1,spare,to,fr)
```

The above code is what I learnt in MIT course on edX, it is solution to Tower of Hanoi problem.

Here the code works fine. So when I want the implementation in reverse order we call the recursive function directly and in correct order we use a return statement, am I right?

Comment: What do you mean by "reversed"?

Comment: Because you print after the recursive call, hense you first perform recursion, and then the "parent" call prints.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Have a look at the Tower of Hanoi code that I just edited in the question, here no return statement is used and still the code works in reverse order

Comment: @a2warik: I think it is probably better to ask a separate question. Now the question looks rather "*chaotic*". Usually asking a lot of subquestions in a single question is discouraged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My question is why is the output of the first code reversed?

It is not really reversed in the *strict* sense, but I think I get what you mean. You perhaps expect that the "parent" call prints before the "child" call.

If we however inspect the code, we see that:

```
def gcdRecur(a,b):
    if b==0:
        print('I am here')
        return a
    else:
        gcdRecur(b,a%b)  # make child call
        print(a,b)       # print from the parent call
```

If you would have swapped the two, it would print in what you probably call the "right way":

```
def gcdRecur(a,b):
    if b==0:
        print('I am here')
        return a
    else:
        # swap printing and recursive calls
        print(a,b)       # print from the parent call
        gcdRecur(b,a%b)  # make child call
```

If you use a `return` statement however, the function is terminated from the moment it reaches a `return`, so if we print things *after* the `return` statement is reached, that printing never happens. In case we want that, we could for instance use a `try`-`finally` construct.

More in depth, if we "*trace*" a program, for example with (this is *not* valid Python code, it is more to give an insight into how these calls are handled):

```
gcdRecur(51,187)
    if 187 == 0:  # fails
    else:  # we take the else branch
        gcdRecur(187,51)
            if 51 == 0:  # fails
            else:  # we take the else branch
                gcdRecur(51,34)
                    if 51 == 0:  # fails
                    else:  # we take the else branch
                        gcdRecur(34,17)
                            if 51 == 0:  # fails
                            else:  # we take the else branch
                                gcdRecur(17,0)
                                    if 0 == 0:  # succeeds!
P                                       print('I am here')
                                        return 17
P                               print(34,17)
P                       print(51,34)
P               print(187,51)
P       print(51,187)
```

I here marked the lines that `print` with a `P` at the left. As you can see, the lines with `P` are in the same order.

Comment: Thank you @WillemVanOnsem, for taking pains to explain the concept in such details. I understood indenting flow but still lack understanding of Unindented portion. But that's fine for now, only more practise will help me understand concepts better.

Answer (score -1):

Of course you should return the return of your call.

You are doing a method that returns something. In your "else" you return nothing.